# Replacing UPDATE SQL vs Drop & Add COLUMN with default value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a requirement to update a text column for all rows of a RDBMS table (**PostgresSQL**) with a fixed text. Currently, table has around 700k records but that is expected to grow. SpringJDBC batch update is slow with following query,

```
UPDATE TABLE TABLENAME SET columnname="FIXED VALUE"
```

This columns is **NULLABLE**. Is it advisable to replace this single UPDATE statement with these two steps?

1. First drop this column from table

2.Readd the column to table specifying default value to be "FIXED VALUE"

I tested code and its very faster than UPDATE statement.

I just wanted to ask you folks if there is any negative side to the approach of dropping and adding column again?

I am running these SQLs in **Java** via **SpringJDBC**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with postgresql is every update require a delete and an insert operation. Do that 700k times and will be very slow and if that field have one index can be even worst.

I dont see any problem with your aproach. I even recreate the whole table for some updates. But you have to be carefull no one else is using that table or are any fk relationship.

```
CREATE table_backup AS 
   SELECT function(field1), function(field2) ....

DROP table_current;

RENAME table_backup to table_current;

CREATE INDEX and CONSTRAINS TO table_current;
```