# Any downside of dropping column constraints ( keys ) and indices before INSERT and UPDATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am using **springJDBC** to do bulk updates ( more than two third records get updated or its an INSERT to an empty table ) to few large tables of **PostgresSQL** DB. These tables have around a million records. Updates and Inserts were very slow. Columns to be updated are participating in either constraints ( primary or foreign keys ) or have indices on them and that seems to be reason of slowness. So I am thinking of removing

1. Primary key constraints

2.Foreign Key constraints

3. Indices

on tables before launching UPDATE and INSERT on them and then recreate these constraints and indices after UPDATE and INSERT are done.

is it a correct approach? any downside of this approach?

No one else be using these tables during that time. I ran a sample code and these is significant improvement in performance.

Comment: The correct approach is staging table

Comment: Slow updates or inserts with FK constraints can only indicate you don't have enough indexes. Post the `create table` statements and the update insert statements you are using. If they contain non-trivial `where` conditions, add the execution plans as well.

Comment: One danger is the constraints failing to enable again if data in the table violates them.

Comment: related to this [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152416/replacing-update-sql-vs-drop-add-column-with-default-value/33153109#33153109)

Comment: yes, these two questions are related and by me. Basically, these two are broad situations where my standalone desktop app takes a lot of time. Columns in other question don't participate in constraints or indices and updated value is a fixed string.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan just in case, I was just providing related information. Not critizing your question.